# Apollo GraphQL remote schema socket hang up

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I have an api gateway which schema stitches a bunch of services together and then provides that merged schema to the front end client. One of my services has a long running resolver (takes greater than 3 min). For some reason after a while my api gateway throws this error.

> Error: request to http://localhost:9002/graphql failed, reason: socket
>   hang up

I haven't been able to find any references to this issue with regards to graphql.

Comment: hi! did you manage to solve it in the end? having exactly the same problem

Comment: no. we no longer go through apollo for websocket connections since apollo federation doesn't support it anyways.

Comment: facing same issue